# How to set wx.LEFT and wx.TOP to two different values in Wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

```
self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border=75)
```

the border of BOTTOM and LEFT is 75, how can i set the border of wx.LEFT to something else
but still apply it to the same item.

Is there something like?:
wx.LEFT = 40
wx.TOP = 130

If I use my code, it will set both wx.LEFT and wx.TOP to 75 (which i do not want). I want to set these items to different values.
If anyone knows the answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

I cannot use

```
self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.LEFT, border=40)
self.sizer.Add(self.listBox, proportion=0, flag=wx.TOP, border=130)
```

It will return an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to nest sizers. So put this sizer itself in a second sizer with the border you want.

Comment: Wow thanks mike, your awesome! I had no idea this was possible!

Comment: Do you know if it possible to add a button in the created space? If I add a button, it will appear to the side of the listbox

Comment: Well, if you make the sizer in the vertical orientation, you should just be able to add another widget. sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL), sizer.Add(myBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to make the position of the button relative to the screen (kind of like wx.EXPAND), Ive tried wx.EXPAND but it does not seem to work, (or do anything).

I am using pos to position the button and wx.VERTICAL with the sizer.

Comment: wx.EXPAND just tells the widget to stretch. You use the border parameter to help position a widget, although it's not as exact as using absolute positioning.